# Issue in lightning Accordion

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am using lightning:accordion component. When ever I am setting some value in it first time it is working fine. But when I change my value it is giving me an error.

```
<lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion" activeSectionName="{!v.object}">
                                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.objectList}" var="sObject">
                                            <lightning:accordionSection name="{!sObject.name}" label="{!sObject.label}">
                                                    <aura:set attribute="body">
                                                        <aura:iteration items="{!sObject.items}" var="item">
                                                            <c:picklistOption label="{!item.label}" name="{!item.name}" selected="{!v.selectedListView}" onSelect="{!c.onListViewSelect}" />
                                                        </aura:iteration>
                                                    </aura:set>
                                            </lightning:accordionSection>
                                    </aura:iteration>
                                </lightning:accordion>
```

in my js on doint I am setting some value.

```
doint: function(component){
   component.set('v.objectsList':[{
         name : 'contact',
         label : 'contact',
         items : [{
             name : 'test contact',
             label : 'Test Contact'         
         }]
}]);
}
```

Then it is working fine.

But if on any other event I am changing values like

```
onChange: function(component){
       component.set('v.objectsList':[{
             name : 'lead',
             label : 'lead',
             items : [{
                 name : 'test lead',
                 label : 'Test lead'         
             }]
    }]);
    }
```

when I set above value and try to open any accordion it is giving me error

> lightning:accordion$controller$handleSectionSelect [Cannot read
>   property 'close' of undefined] Failing descriptor:
>   {lightning:accordion$controller$handleSectionSelect}

Comment: You are referring `close` property of some variable which its complaining does not exists. In you code I cannot see anything causing issue. try commenting few lines until error goes away?

Comment: Actually error is coming in accordion as given in error stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like when you are loading the initial data, you are introducing a `contact` item to your `lightning:accordion`. 
But after doing a change you remove it, by just replacing it with `lead`.

So when it refreshes, it trys to close `contact` and open `lead`, but you stole the contact already from your data.

Try to push the new value, without overriding the old value, if this is an option for you:

```
onChange: function(component){
    var obejcts = component.get('v.objectsList');

    obejcts.append({
         name : 'lead',
         label : 'lead',
         items : [{
             name : 'test lead',
             label : 'Test lead'         
         }]
    });

    component.set('v.objectsList', objects);
}
```

If this isn't an option for you, consider adding a isRendered attritbute and hide the element when you don't need it, so you won't need to refresh the whole component/page.

```
var types = component.get('v.objectsList');

for(var sObjectType of types) {
    sObjectType.isRendered = false;
}

types.append({
    name : 'lead',
    label : 'lead',
    isRendered : true,


<lightning:accordionSection class="{!sObject.isRendered ? '' : 'slds-hide'}" 
                            name="{!sObject.name}" label="{!sObject.label}">
```

Comment: yes @basti you are right with your observation. But my use case is to replace content thats why problem is cominng

Comment: @ManjotSingh updated my answer.